# How to run a python script and upload the generated to dropbox on a server?

Tags: python, dropbox

I wrote a python script which downloads data via the Yahoo! Finance API and puts it into a file. After that, it uploads the file to Dropbox. The script does that every 10 minutes.
How can I implement this at a minimal cost with a server? I don't want to let my computer run 24/7.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: buy a shared sever hosting account with python/cgi support, or even a free one, you can even do it with google app engine probably. You'll need to use [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api) to upload your files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script is gonna run every 10 minutes, EC2 etc. won't do you any good since they are priced based on 15-minute time slices (and the server will always be used).

The cheapest solution is a small VPS, which can be found for as little as 5$ / month from some providers. Install dropbox & python and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Get a micro EC2 instance from Amazon, or a similarly-priced super small server elsewhere.  [Install dropbox on the server](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx).  Set your job to run via cron.

There are ways to do this without provisioning your own server, but it's hard to beat the price of a micro EC2 instance.